# Is it possible to use a generic type parameter on a blazor page?

Tags: generics, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is it possible to use a generic type parameter on a page?

```
@page "/mypage"
@typeparam TDbContext where TDbContext : DbContext
<MyComponent TDbContext="TDbContext" />
```

If this is allowed, where do I define the type that I want to use when the page is initiated?

(My use-case is a page within a component library, that has a sub-component that needs the type dependency defined, for example `MyAppDbContext` passed in from the respective App).

Comment: "MyAppDbContext passed in from the respective App" - how exactly?

Comment: @ℍℍ On a component you can define `@typeparam TDbContext where TDbContext : DbContext`